# How to add location background in manifest.json

Tags: zendesk-app

From the default app setup manifest.json contains this

```
"location": { "zendesk":
    { "ticket_sidebar": "assets/iframe.html" }
}
```

I want part of the script run in background. So how to add background location in this manifest.json?

Like I tried

```
"location": { "zendesk":
    { "ticket_sidebar": "assets/iframe.html" },
    { "background": "assets/iframe.html" }
}
```

but not work.

Comment: Do you want your app to pre-load whenever you refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Zendesk App Framework version 2. Try using the following snippet:

```
"location":{"support":{"ticket_sidebar": "assets/iframe.html"},{"background": "assets/iframe.html"}}
```

In case you are using Zendesk Framework version 1 you would need to specify location as: "location": ["ticket_sidebar","background"]